# Using conditional formatting in excel, I want to highlight the value in the range if matches with value given in cell B1

Tags: conditional-formatting

Using conditional formatting in excel, I want to highlight the value in the range if matches with value given in cell  B1.

Comment: Ok. That's nice. Good luck with that. Did you have a programming question? This site is for questions, not a place to dump your to-do/i-want lists.

Comment: Do you know the answer?

Comment: My understanding is that you can place the formula you want to use in a cell and then create a new rule with the option "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"

Comment: I tried, the only problem I am facing is with "/" that is middle of the text. Its not allowing to match the text. When I remove this "/", i am able to do. but keeping "/" is mandatory in text.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the relevant range is as in example, select A1:A10 and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=A1=B$1
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select choice of formatting, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

[image: SO39986302 example]